# Google sheets countif same date

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have two columns. The first one records when a signup happens (with the time), and the second one is a simple date increment that should count how many signups happened within that day.

For example, for `2022-07-13`, the answer should be `2` (`2022-07-13 2:32:12` and `2022-07-13 12:30:59`)

My formula was: `=COUNTIF(A:A,TO_TEXT(B2&"*"))`

- Turn `2022-07-13` date into a `text`, and look for `2022-07-13*` matches in `A:A`, so I was expecting that `2022-07-13 2:32:12` and `2022-07-13 12:30:59` show up, however it is still showing `0`

Comment: The same question was recently - see [**Google Sheets, SumIf date in cell matches another date**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/165463/297772)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need COUNTIFS() instead COUNTIF()

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A,">="&B2,A2:A,"<"&(B2+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rearrange your sheet to something more "readable" and use the following **single** formula:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(B2:B22), 
    COUNTIF(INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A22," ")),,1),B2:B22),))
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges according to your needs)*

**Functions used:**

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)